# Дважды вызывается OnCreate после возвращения в приложение

Tags: android, activity

После того, как активити уничтожается из-за нехватки памяти, вися в фоне, само собой, при возвращении в приложение OnCreate вызывается два раза. У меня в OnCreate добавляется фрагмент, со списком внутри и инициализируется Toolbar. И выходит, что на форме бывает два комплекта иконок тулбара и два одинаковых фрагмента

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initNavigationView();
    getAds();
}
```

Как можно избежать подобного двойного пересоздания?

UPD вот код initNavigationView

```
   private void initNavigationView() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() == null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            hideSoftKeyboard(MainActivity.this);
            if (getActiveFragments().size() > 1) {
                onBackPressed();
            } else {
                if (!mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Так а  в чем вопрос-то?

Comment: @koks_rs, как избежать подобного поведения

Comment: По фрагментам: `if (savedInstanceState == null) { initNavigationView(); }` С тулбаром не понял.

Comment: @makavelka,  ну так очищайте и сохраняйте ресурсы при onPause() и загружайте при onCreate().  Либо сделать проверку че там уже загружено и не загружать второй раз.

Comment: @lsillarionov, у тулбара есть одна кнопка, но при пересоздании активити их становится две одинаковых

Comment: @makavelka Фрагмент нужно добавлять в активность только при первоначальном создании активности, при пересоздании его добавит сам фрейморк. Похоже, что вы это не учитываете. Покажите код initNavigationView(). Тулбар у вас во фрагменте?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно разбиндить UI и освобождать все ресурсы в *onPause()*.

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unbindDrawables(rootView);
    // разбиндить тулбар и т.п.
    // ...
}

public static void unbindDrawables(View view) {
    if (view != null) {
        if (view.getBackground() != null) {
            view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
        }
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
            }
            try {
                ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
            } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
                //
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Это может понадобиться только в особых, достаточно специфических случаях. Думаю, вам стоит указать, когда и собственно зачем